# JPA error in named parameters wher using count()

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Hi, I have this simple table in mysql:

```java
+---------------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_documento_referencia_importa | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_tipo_documento               | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tipo                            | char(1) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_tipo_documento_origen        | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| estado_documento_origen_antes   | char(1) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| estado_documento_origen_despues | char(1) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this entity:

```java
public class DocumentoReferenciaImporta implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id_documento_referencia_importa")
  private Integer idDocumentoReferenciaImporta;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "tipo")
  private char tipo;
  @JoinColumn(name = "estado_documento_origen_despues", referencedColumnName = "estado_documento")
  @ManyToOne
  private EstadoDocumento estadoDocumentoOrigenDespues;
  @JoinColumn(name = "estado_documento_origen_antes", referencedColumnName = "estado_documento")
  @ManyToOne
  private EstadoDocumento estadoDocumentoOrigenAntes;
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_documento_origen", referencedColumnName = "id_tipo_documento")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private TipoDocumento idTipoDocumentoOrigen;
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo_documento", referencedColumnName = "id_tipo_documento")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private TipoDocumento idTipoDocumento;
  [...snip...]
```

the table reference another table, id_tipo_documento, that is a simple id-name table. 
Somewhere in the code I have this JPA query, that is working perfectly:

```java
String jpql="SELECT o FROM DocumentoReferenciaImporta o "
        + "WHERE o.idTipoDocumentoOrigen.idTipoDocumento = :idTipoDocumento "
        + "AND o.idTipoDocumentoOrigen.idTipoDocumento = :idTipoDocumento2 "
        + "AND o.tipo = :tipo";
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql, DocumentoReferenciaImporta.class);
query.setParameter("idTipoDocumento",102);
query.setParameter("idTipoDocumento2", 103);
query.setParameter("tipo",'R');
query.getResultList();
```

In another function I need to count the records, so I do:

```java
String jpql="SELECT COUNT(o) FROM DocumentoReferenciaImporta o "
        + "WHERE o.idTipoDocumentoOrigen.idTipoDocumento = :idTipoDocumento "
        + "AND o.idTipoDocumentoOrigen.idTipoDocumento = :idTipoDocumento2 "
        + "AND o.tipo = :tipo";
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql, DocumentoReferenciaImporta.class);
query.setParameter("idTipoDocumento",102);
query.setParameter("idTipoDocumento2", 103);
query.setParameter("tipo",'R');
query.getResultList();
int count = ((Integer)q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

this query, instead, give me an error like:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument idTipoDocumento2 not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution.
```

Additionally every application deployment result in a different error: sometimes the argument causing the error is idTipoDocumento2, sometimes is idTipoDocumento, sometimes is tipo.
I am doing something wrong or there's a problem with JPA an COUNT?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything you have looks good, maybe there is an issue with COUNT and JPA. I don't normally use COUNT in my queries. I would replace COUNT(o) with just o and then do query.getResultList().size() to get the count

Comment: Thank for your reply. Actually I'm doing that, but of course I prefer to be able to use count for performance.

Comment: Ah yea, that is true. Hmm "select count(o) from table o;" does not work for me in mysql, I have to do "select count(*) from table o;"

Comment: That's not a MySQL native query, it's a JPA query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is also something else wrong, but at least there is following problems:

Following is never true, because value cannot be both 102 and 103;

```
o.idTipoDocumentoOrigen.idTipoDocumento = :idTipoDocumento //parameter 102
AND o.idTipoDocumentoOrigen.idTipoDocumento = :idTipoDocumento2 //parameter 103
```

COUNT function in JPQL returns Long. That's why second argument to createQuery should be Long.class.

```
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql, Long.class);
```

Comment: yeah, you're right, but it's a copy paste problem from the original, the query is right in the code. anyway if a where in a count query is never true it should return 0, not throw an error :)